# Anulgar - Need the result of the request before view HTML content when start app or refresh

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs6

I'm having a problem that I want to resolve the best way. I have a request from the backend that send me a list of object `{key, value}` that is an enum, and the description of this enum. I need to use this description to "translate" the enum that I have in my code in some component. What I use is a pipe like this `{{ enum | translateEnum }}` this returns the description to show to the user. What I did is a Map that stores the enum as a key and the description as a value. So far so good I guess.

My problem: when I start the app or do a refresh and when the pipe triggers, the Map is empty because the request has been made but not have yet the result. (I trigger the request after the login). What is the best way to handle this? I'm switching to observable the Map in service but the need to subscribe this Map in every component and need to do a get like this

`{{ enumsMap.has(enum) ? enumsMap.get(enum) : enum}}`

seems not good. Any suggestions to do this other way?

All this because I see first the page only after I will receive the result of the request. After that everything works because the Map has content.

The pipe: (old version that I'm switching over)

```
  transform(value: string): string {
    let valueTranslated = value;

    if (this.translateStatusService.enumsMap.has(value)) {
      valueTranslated = this.translateStatusService.enumsMap.get(value);
    }

    return valueTranslated;
  }
```

The service that gets the request (Already with observable):

```
export class TranslateStatusService {
  
  private enumTranslateBehavior = new BehaviorSubject<Map<string, string>>(undefined);
  enums$ = this.enumTranslateBehavior.asObservable();

  enumsMap: Map<string, string>;

  domainURL = `${environment.API_BASE_URL}`;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.enumsMap = new Map<string, string>(undefined);
    this.saveStatusTranslations();
  }

  getStatusTranslations() {
    return this.http.get(`${this.domainURL}/enums/list`);
  }

  saveStatusTranslations() {
    this.getStatusTranslations().subscribe(mainEnum => {
      mainEnum['enums'].forEach(enumObject => {
        this.enumsMap.set(enumObject['name'], enumObject['description']);
      });
      this.enumTranslateBehavior.next(this.enumsMap);
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you implement a custom and the async pipes together. It would solve your problem. Just make your enum as Observable and use two pipes. For example, `enum$ | translateEnum | async`.

Comment: Hey thanks for the tip. 
My enum is actually an object property so is object.status for example, I can´t transform it to an observable. The enum$ is observable that I have in my service with the list.
I figure it out this in pipe:

`
  transform(value: string): string {
    let valueTranslated = value;

    this.translateStatusService.enums$.pipe(take(2),
    ).subscribe(enumMap => valueTranslated = enumMap.get(value));;

    return valueTranslated;
  }
`
This waits for the request and shows the correct value. I'm not sure if it's the best but seems what I want.